# Reading /proc/kcore file

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system

I am trying to read the kcore file in the /proc directory using the command 
cat /proc/kcore but something is coming in unreadable form. Is this possible to read this kcore file ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/proc/kcore is not a text file. It's a representation of your RAM.

```
$ hexdump /proc/kcore | head
```

Answer (score 1):

Use gdb with the kcore as follows:

```
gdb vmlinux /proc/kcore
```